# C# isn't detecting my static Main() for an entry point

Tags: c#, .net

Visual Studio 2019 is acting like this static void Main() doesn't exist.

```
using System;

namespace Paint
{

    class Program
    {
        void static Main(string[] args)
        {
            Paint();
        }
        void Paint()
        {
            string[] tiles = new string[256];
            var newkey = Console.Read();
            int paint = Convert.ToInt32(newkey);
            tiles[paint] = "Test";
            Console.WriteLine(tiles[paint]);
            Console.Beep();
            Console.ReadKey();
            Paint();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put the Main() at the front of the function, but that didn't work.

Comment: Is your file named `<something>.cs` like `program.cs`? Also: the compiler should complain about some errors. `void static` should be `static void` and the `Paint()` method should be static as well.

Comment: Nope, I dunno what

Comment: please send your error.why do you use Paint in method name and Namespace(must is different) and why do you use at end line of Method that you call method again(cause of your app never stop)

Comment: **i dont know.** error is Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point Paint C:\Users\username\source\repos\Gravity Engine\Gravity Engine\CSC 1 Active

Comment: Do not ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: yeah thats what im trying not to do

Comment: I've **literally** given you the answer/solution in my first comment: `void static` should be `static void` and the `Paint()` method should be `static` as well.

Comment: didnt work breh ;-;

Comment: [It **does**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JQ6djr) as opposed to [your code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lZSf0k), and don't call me breh.

Comment: it didnt work for me thats what im saying

Comment: Then tell us WHAT doesn't work. WHAT errors you get. "It doesn't work" is not helpful.

Comment: All I had to do was ignore the error. Wow, thanks alot, Microsoft.

Comment: DON'T ignore errors. And provide a decent [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, don't blame MS; it's 99.9999% surely *you* who's at fault here. You're new at this, remember?

Comment: i just ran it and then it said no errors

Comment: Alright. My problem is solved, but earlier it didn't work??? Oh well, it's solved now.

Comment: please somebody make a post so i can mark this as "Solved"

Comment: Why'd you accept abolfazl sadeghi's answer?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is

#1.add static before Methods

#2.change Name Method

#3.comment   // Paint();

if you want recursive or repeat Method that you must review and change your code

this is correct code

```
using System;

namespace Paint;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Paintn();
    }
    static void Paintn()
    {
        string[] tiles = new string[256];
        var newkey = Console.Read();
        int paint = Convert.ToInt32(newkey);
        tiles[paint] = "Test";
        Console.WriteLine(tiles[paint]);
        Console.Beep();
        Console.ReadKey();
       // Paint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Commenting out `Paint()` changes functionality. Who's to say it wasn't intended to be a loop? (Though it will eventually stack-overflow, ironically...)

Comment: You did not specify the end method and this code will be executed endlessly

Comment: Maybe it was _intended_ to be executed endlessly?

Comment: if you want method  executed endlessly,you can out of comment,else You must specify the end method(with if)

Comment: What does "you must specify the end method(with if)" even mean?

Comment: condition for finish run method:for example if (paint != -1)  Paintn();

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure your file is named `<something>.cs` like `program.cs`
2. The compiler should complain about some errors:

   1. `void static` should be `static void`
   2. The `Paint()` method should be `static` as well

```cs
using System;

namespace Paint
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Paint();
        }
        static void Paint()
        {
            string[] tiles = new string[256];
            var newkey = Console.Read();
            int paint = Convert.ToInt32(newkey);
            tiles[paint] = "Test";
            Console.WriteLine(tiles[paint]);
            Console.Beep();
            Console.ReadKey();
            Paint();
        }
    }
}
```